# CUDA Illegal Address

Tags: cycles-render-engine, performance, tilesize

Hi I have recently just installed Blender 2.93.0 onto my work PC. I have a file that has my models and scene setup on Google drive, where I launch the file from. I have selected GPU Compute and I am using the Cycles render engine.

The graphics card I am using is :
Nvidia GTX 1080

When I press render, it stops rendering and an error pops up on top of the render window, saying CUDA error Illegal address.

I have searched about this on the internet and have found no other alternative than reducing the tile sizes. I have tried different tile sizes, as small as 8x8 pixels, however it still does not work. Parts within the centre of the image render and then it renders some of the tiles around it and stops without finishing the render.

Within the Nvidia control panel, in Manage 3D Settings, the CUDA - GPUs setting has 'All' selected.

When I run the same file on my laptop, the file renders, however the GPU on my PC is stronger than the other, therefore I would like to render this on my PC.

Is there a page or someone that I can directly get some technical advice from?

I need to figure this out as soon as possible, as I have a deadline coming up soon. I would appreciate it if any one has any solutions.

Update: I have tried uninstalling the current drivers, restarting the PC and downloading the latest from the NVIDIA website and installing them. The issue seems to remain.

Comment: Is it the same tiles that get rendered every time, or does it seem arbitrary?

Comment: Are your graphics drivers up to date?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard sometimes it renders arbitrary and sometimes it doesn't render at all

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I think that they are, I will double check this and get back to you